# Could not get Captcha image in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, captcha

I am trying to create a login page. I want to add captcha image using CI's helper but couldn't succeed it.

**Login.php**

```
class Login extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function index() {

        $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url', 'captcha'));

        $captchaSettings = array(
            'img_path' => base_url() . 'captcha',
            'img_url' => base_url() . 'captcha',
            'font_path' => base_url() . 'system/fonts/captcha4.ttf',
            'img_width' => '300',
            'img_height' => '40',
            'expiration' => '3600',
            'word_length' => 6,
            'font_size' => 16,
            'img_id' => 'captchaImage',
            'pool' => '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ',
            // White background and border, black text and red grid
            'colors' => array(
                'background' => array(255, 255, 255),
                'border' => array(255, 255, 255),
                'text' => array(0, 0, 0),
                'grid' => array(255, 40, 40)
            )
        );

        $dataCaptcha = create_captcha($captchaSettings);
        $this->load->view('login_form', array('captcha' => $dataCaptcha));

    }
}
```

*login_form.php* takes captcha image but show `boolean false` when I use `var_dump` to see what it contains.

```
<?php var_dump($captcha); //boolean false?>
```

It looks like `create_captcha()` returns `false` instead of an image. So I cannot get image. But I did what the tutorial says.

Comment: https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/captcha_helper.html `Using the captcha helper` requirements. Shouldn't it be `img_url`?

Comment: @ofirbaruch yes, it should be. After changing it still returns boolean false.

Comment: Consider adding a `/` after the `base_url() . 'captcha'`.
BTW how come for `path` and `url` you're using the same value? URL should include `www....` while path is something like: `/directory/...`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to CodeIgniter API for the [`create_captcha`](http://apigen.juzna.cz/doc/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/source-function-create_captcha.html#42-240) function those are the possible reasons for getting a Boolean false.

```
 61:         if ($img_path == '' OR $img_url == '')
 62:         {
 63:             return FALSE;
 64:         }
 65: 
 66:         if ( ! @is_dir($img_path))
 67:         {
 68:             return FALSE;
 69:         }
 70: 
 71:         if ( ! is_writable($img_path))
 72:         {
 73:             return FALSE;
 74:         }
 75: 
 76:         if ( ! extension_loaded('gd'))
 77:         {
 78:             return FALSE;
 79:         }
```

**So make sure that:**

1. You send the img_path and img_url parameters (Notice my comment
   regarding a possible typo in the parameter's name).
2. The img_path is an existing directory which is also writable
3. You have the GD extension installed.

**Path/URL**

I believe it's because you're using `base_url() . 'captcha'` as your `img_path`.
`base_url()` returns a url in the format of: `http://www.domain.com/` while path should be in another format (relative), something like: `./directory/captache/`.

Comment: it worked for me I changed my code like this  `** 'img_path'=>'img/captcha/', 'img_url'=> base_url().'img/captcha/' **`